# Pricing model for Bluemix Toolchain

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools, devops-services, eclipse-orion

I have to setup a Project in Bluemix and I have a Bluemix subscription. I want to know what additional costs will I have if I setup a private Git Repository hosted in Bluemix. Additionally what if I integrate this with Toolchain?

Further, what are the restrictions in terms of file size or project size or any other that I will have if I move to a hosted environment for entire Source Code Management in Bluemix

Comment: Cannot understand why is this under-rated. Can someone pls explain

Comment: I think some people downvoted it because it doesn't really meet the question requirements here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

It really depends on which services you integrate. The information in this section of the Bluemix docs probably can help: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/pricing/estimating_costs.html#cost

Comment: I suspect it's because SO is supposed to be about technical questions, and this is more of a business question. I've posted an answer, but if you need more details I suggest posting under the `devops-services` topic at [DeveloperWorks](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/devops-services/).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the new [IBM Bluemix Continuous Delivery](https://bluemix.net/devops/getting-started) offering (the older [JazzHub](https://hub.jazz.net) service is deprecated and shutting down soon). The only [pricing plan for CD](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/continuous-delivery) at the moment is the Free plan. This includes public or private repositories hosted by IBM (built on GitLab Community Edition), the build and deployment Pipeline, Eclipse Orion based Web IDE, plus integration with various other IBM and 3rd party services including Slack and Sauce Labs.